# Want to create a synchronized data download in servlet action

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety, mutex

I want to create a servlet method like below. In this method I want to perform some data download.So if request for data download comes I just do the download. If already a download is going on I want somehow the second request to wait till the first thread is done with download. Once the first thread is done with download the second thread can start automatically.

```
DoTheDownloadAction(){

}
```

How can i achieve the above requirement?

Comment: The downloads will become incredible slow, if you connect many clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have a `DownloadHelper` class and in your Servlet you have created one instance of that class then you can do something like this :

```
DoTheDownloadAction() {
   synchronized(downloadHelper) {
      //Downloading something
   }
}
```

Lets imagine you have a button called as "download" with id="download" in your jsp and you have this code in your javascript

```
var globalDownloadStatus = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#download'(.click(function(){
       if(globalDownloadStatus == true) {
           alert('download already in progress, please wait');
           return;
       }
       jQuery.get('yourservletpath', function(data){
          alert('Download Complete');
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: I will have a jsp page also which will display that an download is currently going on. Soe if the user wants to do second download he shoud get a message that one downloading is already going on. How i can achieve this?

Comment: hmm in this case you need a download counter at your jsp page, say you are using ajax and you have a flag to check if download is finished or not, if flag is false then inform the user or else start the download

Comment: Can you please help me more. Might be you can help in in designing the jsp page as well as the action class. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the perfect candidate for a semaphore, or (depending on the complexity and the downstream effects) the simpler way to affect the same change would be to synchronize the download code to a relevant key for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Take in account that usually web-servers could distributed for scalability. Usually the appropriate solution is to synchronize via database locks. However for you maybe just enough to use `synchronized` java keyword on an object you want wait to.

Also, you are asking for a pessimistic lock. It's usually bad architecture design.

Comment: I will have a jsp page also which will display that an download is currently going on. Soe if the user wants to do second download he shoud get a message that one downloading is already going on. How i can achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a database? If so, then keep the downloading state here. Then somebody starts download, change a record. Then somebody tries - check the record. If you want java-only solution, use the `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock#tryLock()`